# Large Residual-Online Outlier Detection for Kalman Filter

Tags: filter, statistics, probability, outliers, kalman-filter

I am trying to find outliers in Residual. I used three algorithms basically if the residuals magnitudes are less, the algorithm performances are good but if the residuals magnitude are big, the algorithm performances are not good.

```
 1) ^=〖(−())〗^ ^(−) (−()) - Chi-Square Test
    if the matrix 3x3 - degree of freedom is 4.
    ^ > 13.277

 2) Residual(i) > 3√(HP ^ + R) - Measurement Covariance Noise

 3) Residual(i) > 3-Sigma
```

I have applied three algorithms to find the outliers. First one is Chi Square Test, second checks Measurement Covariance Noise, Third looks the 3 sigma.

Can you give any suggestion about the algorithms or I can implement a new way if you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The third case cannot be correct for all case because if there is a large residual, will fail. The second one is more stable because it is related to measurement noise covariance so that your residual should change according to the measurement covariance error.

Comment: The second approach is better but I need to try a different method. Because I am not sure these algorithms are useful for all case. Because I have different measurement